# What days should we be fasting?

Tags: fasting, yogi, ekadashi, purnima

What days in the month is best for the body to fast for good health? I only know about Ekadashi and I think Purnima. Is there more specific days?

Comment: Ekadashi, Chaturdashi, Purnima, Amavasya, Chaturthi, etc... tithis are used for fasting. Various deities rule various Tithis and thus each tithi has its own importance... Similarly fasting based on week day also are done like fasting on Monday, fasting on Tuesday... Similarly fasting on Sankranti day of each month.. as well as fasting on specific festivals like ShivaRatri, Navaratri, Sukharatri, Ramanavami, Janmashtami, etc.. are done...

Comment: there is a little misunderstanding here, I was thinking of fasting events that happens every month like ekadashi,purnima and I think Amavasya, is there any other fasting events happening every month?